# string append for roman numerals

Tags: c++

Im reading Problem Solving with C++ and dont understand the following:

- in row 27 seems like the greater than and less than signs are backwards but when i change them to what i think they should be the program does run. Please could you let me know why the <> signs are they are?
- in the string function starting in row 47, how does it know which string to chose? thinking if i input the year 1930, for 900 the program somehow knows hows to go over 9 commas to chose the next string which is 'CM', and likewise for 30 it knows it needs to go over 3 commas and chose 'XXX'...but im not certain? Please could you let me know how it knows to chose 'CM' & 'XXX' using my example of the year 1930.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


//function prototype
string toRomanLiterals(int);

int main()
//program displays Arabic Years as Roman Years
{
//declare integer as number
int integernumber;
//declare a character
char choice;

//do while loop to continue by y or no
do
{
   //do while loop to read integer from user
   //read integer number between 1 and 3000 only
   do
   {
       cout << "Enter a number between 1000 and 3000: ";
       cin >> integernumber;
   }
   while (integernumber < 1000 || integernumber > 3000);

   if (integernumber > 1000 || integernumber < 3000)
   {
       //calling toRomanLiterals function
       string output= toRomanLiterals(integernumber);
       cout << output<<endl;
   }
   //continue to ask until user wishes to stop
   cout << "Would you like to continue? [y/n]" << endl;
   cin >> choice;

}
while (choice != 'n');
return 0;
}

//string toRomanLitrals takes the integer number and converts to a given
//number to a Roman number if it is between 1000 and 3000

string toRomanLiterals(int number)
{
string roman;
int th,h,t,o;

//string array for numbers 1 to 9
string ones[] =
{"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
//string array for numbers 10 to 90
string tens[] =
{"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
//string array for numbers 100 to 900
string hundreds[] =
{"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
//string array for numbers 1000 to 3000
string thousands[] = {"", "M", "MM", "MMM"};

if (number <= 3000)
{
    //get number of thousands
    th = number/1000;
    number = number % 1000;

    //get number of hundreds
    h = number/100;
    number = number % 100;

    //get number of tens
    t = number/10;
    o = number % 10;

    //concatenate all string values of thousands, hundreds, tens, zeros
    //concatenate all symbols

    roman += thousands[th].append(hundreds[h])
            .append(tens[t]).append(ones[o]);

}
return roman;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "backwards"? Can you capitalize the first letter of each sentence properly? Where are the apostrophes?

Answer (score -1):

> in row 27 seems like the greater than and less than signs are backwards but when i change them to what i think they should be the program does run. Please could you let me know why the <> signs are they are?

So the program will request again for the input for `integernumber`, if the input was not between 1000 and 3000.

> in the string function starting in row 47, how does it know which string to chose? thinking if i input the year 1930, for 900 the program somehow knows hows to go over 9 commas to chose the next string which is 'CM', and likewise for 30 it knows it needs to go over 3 commas and chose 'XXX'...but im not certain? Please could you let me know how it knows to chose 'CM' & 'XXX' using my example of the year 1930.

For your example number, 1930,

```
th = number/1000; // th gets 1
number = number % 1000; // number is now 930

h = number/100; // h gets 9
number = number % 100; // number is now 30

t = number/10; // t gets 3
o = number % 10; // o gets 0

roman += thousands[th].append(hundreds[h])
        .append(tens[t]).append(ones[o]);
// gets the numerals "M", "CM", "XXX" and "", and appends them together, getting "MCMXXX"
```

In summary, the function extracts from the number, digit by digit, and then gets roman numeral for them, and appends them, and gets the answer.

Also, **please don't use the dreaded `using namespace std`!** it very likely will cause name collision and break anything apart.

Comment: Thanks to recap for my own benefit, in the string toRomanLiterals function are the 'th', 'h', 't', 'o' which indicates the data point in the array to use?

Comment: Yes. `th` got 1, and thus `thousands[th]` is `"M"`, and so on.